# Django Model field calculated from other fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

There are quite a few other questions here around this but none of them have helped.

I would like a `yield` field to be calculated by `yield = starts / finishes` fields. I'd like to graph it using Highcharts.

However when I add an object via Admin portal - it's setting `yield = 0` and won't calculate.

models.py:

```
class wYield(models.Model):
    starts = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    finishes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)


## ONE: i've tried the below:
    yield_num = model.FloatField()
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.starts > 0:
             self.yield = self.finishes / self.starts 
        else:
             self.yield = 0
        super(wYield, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

## TWO: i've tried this but then I don't know how to see it in the Admin view:
    def _set_yield(self):
        if self.starts > 0:
             x = self.finishes / self.starts 
        else:
             x = 0
        return x
    yield_num = property(_set_yield)

 ## THREE: I think this works the same as TWO
    @property
    def yield_num(self):
        if self.starts > 0:
             return self.finishes / self.starts
        else:
             return 0
```

admin.py:

```
from .models import wYield

class wYieldAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('starts', 'finishes', 'yield_num')

admin.site.register(wYield, wYieldAdmin)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out (w the help of AbhiP!) Python `int` typecasting was the main culprit. Stupid problem to have!

Below is what worked, and allowed me to not save the calculated field (but display it and make it act like a field in the model):

```
@property
def yield_num(self):
    if self.starts > 0:
        #needed the float() to cast it out of an int
        return self.finishes / float(self.starts)
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't have to save it on the db every time as it can be calculated on the fly; otherwise you'd be wasting space. Not to mention duplicity in the db values.

Also, if tomorrow your logic changes for `yield` you will have full freedom to do it on to your `lambda` expressions. Here's one example:

```
Class wYieldAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    yield = lambda self: (self.finishes / self.starts) if self.starts > 0 else 0
    yield.short_description = 'Yield'
    list_display = ('starts', 'finishes', 'yield')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Class wYieldAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
yield = lambda self: (self.finishes / self.starts) if self.starts > 0 else 0
yield.short_description = 'You have a big head'
list_display = ('starts', 'finishes', 'yield')
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!